# iis7 url rewrite messing page up

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

i have the following rewrite rule in place

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
             <rule name="1stLevelRule">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?url={R:1}" />
            </rule>
           <rule name="2ndLevelRule">
                <match url="^([0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9a-z-]+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?url={R:1}/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

however for some reason it seems to be changing all the images and css on the page, has anyone else had the same issue and can anyone tell me how to stop it doing it

thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the file its self was matching the first rule but the images js etc were matching the second rule

the fix is very simple

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
             <rule name="1stLevelRule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([0-9a-z-]+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?url={R:1}" />
               <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
               </conditions>
            </rule>
           <rule name="2ndLevelRule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9a-z-]+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?url={R:1}/{R:2}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```